# How do I create and download scalable fonts to Zebra P4T

Tags: printing, fonts, zebra-printers, scalable

So, I've been tasked with making several of our in-house applications print using the Zebra P4T printers.  Communicating with them has been rather pain free.

However, I need a scalable font for part of it.  I read the manual, and boy that sounds easy.  Downloading a font **is easy**.  But I've yet to find a way to create a scalable font.  Zebra tech support has been less than helpful, going so far as to tell me that it cannot be done, even though their documentation says it can.

I've used the Zebra Font Downloader, and can create all sorts of .CPF files to push to the printer, but can't figure out how to make a .CSF (scalable) one. There doesn't seem to be an option to make a font scalable before you download it.

This brings me here, as I'm about to pull out my already grey hair.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution, since I couldn't install the third-party driver as someone else suggested.

Instead, we setup a virtual machine running Windows XP, and installed Zebra's 'Label Designer' software.  Then I used that to make scalable fonts. From there it was easy to transfer said fonts to a network drive, and send them to the printers.